# Как передать php сессию через jquery для авторизации

Tags: php, jquery, авторизация, сессия

Сделал авторизацию с jquery и обработкой в php. Все работает хорошо, ошибки высвечиваются, если данные введены верно то человека перенаправляет на следующую страницу.

До этого я сталкивался только с php (сессиями), jquery только сейчас начал применять, в нем практически как и вообще в js еще плохо разбираюсь, просто стала такая задача.

Но возникла проблема с сессией, она через jquery не передается, можете подсказать, как решить эту проблему?

```html
<form id="ajax_form" method="POST" action="" >
    <div id="result_form"></div>
        <input class="input" placeholder="ВВЕДИ СВОЕ ИМЯ!" type="text" name="name" required>
        <input class="input" type="password" placeholder="ВВЕДИ СВОЙ ПАРОЛЬ!" name="password" required>
        <input type="button" id="btn" value="Войти">
</form>
```

```js
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $("#btn").click(

        function(){
            sendAjaxForm('result_form', 'ajax_form', 'lib/auth.php');
            return false; 
        }
    );

});

// слушаю файл обработчик и пеердаю его ответы пользователю
function sendAjaxForm(result_form, ajax_form, url) {
    $.ajax({
        url:     url, 
        type:     "POST", 
        dataType: "html", 
        data: $("#"+ajax_form).serialize(), 
        success: function(response) { 
            // если при авторизации произошла ошибка, высвечиваю текст ошибки
            $(response).clone();
            $('#result_form').append(response);
            $('#result_form').css({'border': '1px solid #ff5151'});

            // удаляю текст ошибки через 3 секунды
            setTimeout(function () {
                $("#result_form").html("").css({'border': 'none'});
            }, 3000);

            // если авторизация успешна, перевожу пользователя на следующую страницу
            if(response == "ok"){
                window.location.href = "history.php"
            }
        },
        // если не сработал скрипт обработчик или данные до него не дошли
        error: function(response) {
            $('#result_form').html('Не предусмотренная Ошибка. Пожалуйста, попробуйте еще раз спустя пару минут.');
        }

    });
}
```

В php обработчике, если логин и пароль верны, получаю по ним из БД id пользователя и указываю сессию следующим образом

```php
session_start();
$_SESSION['user_id'] = $user_id;
```

И в самом начале страницы на которую идет переадресация в jquery "history.php" указываю

```php
<?php
session_start();
$user_id = $_SESSION['user_id'];
?>
```

Прошу прощения если вопрос слишком глупый

Comment: Посмотрите в консоле браузера, какие заголовки и куки возвращает вам ajax запрос. Присутствует ли в запросе сессионная кука и передается ли эта кука на скрипт history.php

Comment: Не мое это конечно дело, но я бы использовал `$_COOKIE` вместо сессий

Comment: 1. Нет, не присутствует (на сколько я правильно конечно понял)
2. Пробовал $_COOKIE, но результат к сожалению тот же :(
3. В итоге решил проблему, но не знаю на сколько это правильно:
 - 1 На странице логина получаю логин \ пароль
 - 2 Отправляю данные ajax - ом в скрипт обработчик
 - 3 В скрипке получаю ID пользователя и передаю его обратно в .js файл (с ajax - ом)
 - 4 Из .js файла перекидываю ID на страницу логина GET запросом и делаю редирект на следующую страницу (history.php)
 - 5 На странице логина получаю ID `$id=$_GET['id'];` и записываю его в сессию